# Set points outside plot to lower and upper limit

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

Maybe this question exists already, but I could not find it.

I am making plots in Python. I don't want to set my axes range such that all points are included - there are some really high or really low values, and all I care about in those points is that they exist - that is, they need to be in the plot, but not on their actual value - rather, somewhere on the top of the canvas.

So i found something that helps a bit in achieving what i want to do in this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894896/set-points-outside-plot-to-upper-limit)

So basically this thing works:

```
xmax=0.18
plt.(np.minimum(x,xmax),y)
```

But when I tried something like this then it didn't work.

```
xmin=0.8 
xmax=0.18
plt.(np.minimum(x, xmin,xmax),y)
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: In the link answers use try this (to do it on the x axis instead of y): `ax.scatter(np.minimum(x, ymax),y)
`

Comment: yeah but that's only for the upper limit of x axis but if i want to add the lower limit as well? Then how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force the points above a threshold to a maximum level you may use `np.minimum(x,xmax)`.
To force the points below a threshold to a minimum level you may use `np.maximum(x,xmin)`.

To do both you may combine the two commands

```
xlimited = np.minimum(np.maximum(x,xmin),xmax)
```

Note that to have the points restricted in the vertical direction you would do this to the `y` values of course.